# SVG text-path direction change on a half circle element

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, text, path

I am trying to get a text-path inside of an SVG to follow the half circle, but i can't get it to start at the correct point.

It's implemented in my project like this

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <path fill="transparent" id="curve" d=" M 400 0 A 200 197 0 1 1 400 -7" />
  <text x="6" width="500">
    <a href='https://google.com'><textPath href="#curve">
      Test text direction
      </textPath></a>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Please check this image https://ibb.co/cv6vWZG to see what i try to get and what i'm getting. The white text is what i'm looking for and the black text is what i'm getting

Comment: I think there is a `side` attribute that might be what you are after

Comment: unfortunately only forks in firefox for now :( @Paulie_D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The text - ***Test text direction*** is located on the curve from the beginning in the `path` formula pointed to by the `M(move)` command.
To change the starting point of the text location, you need to swap the `beginning` and `end` of the curve.

It was:

`d=" M 400 0 A 200 197 0 1 1 400 -7"`

It became:

`d=" M 0 0 A 200 200 0 0 0 400 0"`

`<tspan dy="-5"` adjusts the text distance from the curve

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
            <path fill="transparent" stroke="black" id="curve" d=" M 0 0 A 200 200 0 0 0 400 0" />
      <a href='https://google.com'>
            <text x="6"  >
            <textPath   xlink:href="#curve">
                  <tspan dy="-5">Test text direction </tspan>
                </textPath>
        </text> 
      </a>
</svg>
```

Adjustment of text location from the beginning of the curve - `startOffset="40%"`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
            <path fill="transparent" stroke="black" id="curve" d=" M 0 0 A 200 200 0 0 0 400 0" />
      <a href='https://google.com'>
            <text x="6"  >
                <textPath   xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="40%">
                  <tspan dy="-5">Test text direction </tspan>
                </textPath>
            </text> 
      </a>
</svg>
```

### Update

> Is there a better way to center the text to center of the curve than
> guess 40% ?

Add `startOffset="50%"`  `text-anchor="middle"`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
            <path fill="transparent" stroke="black" id="curve" d=" M 0 0 A 200 200 0 0 0 400 0" />
      <a href='https://google.com'>
            <text x="6"  >
                <textPath   xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="50%"  text-anchor="middle" >
                  <tspan dy="-5">Test text direction </tspan>
                </textPath>
            </text> 
      </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: this worked thank you very much, one more question while we at it:
Is there a better way to center the text to center of the curve than guess 40% ? @Alexandr_TT

Comment: @srdjan_susa Added option to center text on a curve